# Question on Moshiach times

Tags: death, messiah

When Moshiach comes (may it be speedily in our days) the posuk says: there will be no more death, does that mean that people are not going to die?
Meaning everyone is going to live forever?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Note you can edit your name unless the number 27154 is very meaningful to you. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Where does a verse say that when Mashiach comes there will be no more death?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Rambam on his Iggeret Techiet Hameitim:

"The individuals who will return to their bodies will eat, drink, marry, and procreate, and they will die after a long life, like those who live during the messianic age. The life, however, that is not followed by death, is life in the world to come, since it will be bodiless."